# How can I go back from a webpage to an Android app?

Tags: php, android, api, android-asynctask, foursquare

I'm trying to create my first Android app in Android Studio that will consume live API data.
To authenticate, I'm following the OAuth 2.0 explanation on [Foursquare Dev](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth).
First, this lets users login and authorize the app. When authorized, it redirects to a php file on my server on http://example.com/apps/apptest/index.php containing the following:

```
<?php

//INIT
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = array();

//AUTH
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$redirectUrl = urlencode("http://example.com/apps/apptest/index.php");
$code = htmlspecialchars($_GET["code"]);

$url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=";
$url .= $clientId;
$url .= "&client_secret=";
$url .= $clientSecret;
$url .= "&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=";
$url .= $redirectUrl;
$url .= "&code=";
$url .= $code;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);

$access_token = $obj->access_token;

$url2 = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=" . $access_token . "&v=" . date("Ymd");
$json2 = file_get_contents($url2);
$obj2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$userId = $obj2['response']['user']['id'];

// some mysql things I skipped in this code snippet
if (success) {
   $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = $access_token;
}
else {
   $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "ERROR";
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

The problem now is: I can't get back from my web page to my android app!
What I want is the user ID and/or token to be given to the app in some way so that I can consume the foursquare API!
I've been trying all day to get this fixed;
-At first I tried to put an html link in the php file redirecting back to the app, didn't work
-Then I tried "consuming" this self written "API" with Asynchronous tasks in Android, didn't work as well.

Now I ran out of options but I don't want to stop this project, so is there anybody who could tell me what I could try next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing the authorisation via a webview?

Comment: I am doing the authorisation with this code: `Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=XXXXXXXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=XXXXXXXX");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);`

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but have you looked at the Foursquare Oauth library for Android? I believe it handles all of this for you https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth

Comment: This library is pretty circuitous to me..

Answer (score 0):

I think deeplinking could solve your problem.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: I will take a look! Thanks for the comment.